# Shift unit in VHDL

Tags: vhdl, fpga, intel-fpga

As part of an alu design for a FPGA course I need to build a Shift unit capable of doing left shift and right arithmetic shift.

I wrote some VHDL code, simulated it in ModelSim and it worked fine. The next step was to compile it for an FPGA (ALTERA DE1). Now all the other operations of the ALU works fine but not the shift unit. For opcodes related to shift the output stays equals to the input.

```
entity Shift is
    generic (
        N : integer := 8 );
    port (
        A,B:in std_logic_vector(N-1 downto 0);
        OP: in std_logic_vector(2 downto 0);
        Enable: in std_logic;
        shiftedA:out std_logic_vector(N-1 downto 0));
end Shift;

architecture rtl of Shift is
begin
    shift_process: process (Enable,op,A,B)
        variable TempVec : std_logic_vector(N-1 downto 0) ;--:= (others => '0');
        variable inVector : std_logic_vector(N-1 downto 0);
        variable bitNum : Integer;
    begin
        inVector:=A;
        TempVec:=A;
        bitNum := conv_integer(B);
        test <= "00000000";
        if Enable = '1' then

            if OP = "100" then
                for i in 1 to bitNum loop
                    TempVec := TempVec(N-2 downto 0) & "0";
                end loop ;

            elsif OP = "101" then
                for j in 1 to bitNum loop
                    TempVec := A(N-1) & TempVec(N-1 downto 1);
                end loop;
            else
                TempVec := (others => '0');
            end if;
        else
            TempVec := (others => '0');
        end if;
        shiftedA <= TempVec;
    end process;
end rtl;
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: VHDL has shift functions, which should synthesize to an efficient barrel shifter.  Or make your own barrel shifter.  But you want to do it in log(N) steps, not N steps and **definitely not your current method which is  2^N**

Comment: Your code example has an error, there is no declaration for `test` and you could comment out it's assignment. The variable `inVector` in `shift_process` isn't used. You don't show your context clause but only use `conv_integer` from Synopsys package std_logic_arith and that appears to require a type conversion of `B` to `unsigned`. Eliminating element-wise loops as Ben indicates using functions would alleviate the need for `TempVec` as well.

Answer (score 4):

Loops, like `for i in 1 to bitNum loop` are unrolled in synthesis for implementation as a circuit, but in this case the end condition for the loop is dependent on data, since `bitNum` is `conv_integer(B)`, so conversion into hardware is a problem.  Simulators can handle such constructions, since they do not convert into a circuit.

There is probably a synthesis warning telling this, so check the warnings, since some are actually relevant.

Telling more will spoil a good exercise... ;-)